# excel import function to force datetimes format in string

Tags: r, excel, datetime, strptime

I'm designing an application (shiny) for people to upload some data from Excel. I'd rather import from xlsx (because my clients are not used to use csv) and i'm blocked with date formats.I want the user to select himself the date format (like "ymd", "ymd_hms", "mdy_hm") from the imported character string.

Problem: most excel libraries that I tested either return a numeric date (43520.22) or auto-recognise the date format, more or less successfully (like if there are no seconds it fails). Can you think of **an import function that takes .xlsx and returns the date column "as is", in character format.**

I tried openxlsx::read.xlsx() and read_xls for instance.
I also thought of importing everything in numeric and then translate to date, but it seems that depending on the excel version the origin date can vary (my users are from different countries).

Some of the possible formats:

[image]

The way I see it in the shiny application:
[image]

And the line of code that would result:

```
<import_xlsx_function>(input$file$datapath) %>% mutate(datetime = datetime %>% lapply(input$CHOICE_dateformat) %>% do.call(c, .))
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the `read_xls` function in package `readxl` does not guess the type and keep dates as character.

Comment: @meriops, indeed this funciton has a option to "guess" columns, which would output date format, and an option "text" that outputs "43209", i.e. a numeric date in character.